# Magento admin template not called

Tags: php, magento

I have created a custom page in admin, and in the left tab, I have called the controller using ajax. In the controller i have called the template file, but the content of the template is not shown
here is my code
Tabs.php

```
 $this->addTab(
        'text_and_images',
        array(
            'label'   => Mage::helper('agile_dynamicproductpage')->__('Add Text and Image'),
            'title'   => Mage::helper('agile_dynamicproductpage')->__('Add Text and Image'),
            'url'   => $this->getUrl('*/*/test'),
            'class' => 'ajax'
        )
    );
```

IndexController.php

```
 public function testAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout('adminhtml_dynamicproductpage_dynamicblock_test');
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

adminlayout.xml

```
<adminhtml_dynamicproductpage_dynamicblock_test>
    <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="dynamicblock" template="agile_dynamicpductpage/test.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_dynamicproductpage_dynamicblock_test>
```

test.phtml

```
<?php echo 'scuccess';?>
```

[image]

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try it in your controller, and remove reference from your xml.

```
<adminhtml_dynamicproductpage_dynamicblock_test>
        <block type="core/template" name="dynamicblock" template="agile_dynamicpductpage/test.phtml"/>
</adminhtml_dynamicproductpage_dynamicblock_test>

        $this->loadLayout('adminhtml_dynamicproductpage_dynamicblock_test');
        $block = $this->getLayout()
        ->getBlock('dynamicblock');
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($block->toHtml());
```